# How to create a state machine from inductive types in Coq?

Tags: coq

How could be created a correct state machine (without a way to construct it in invalid way) in Coq entirely from inductive types?

Starting from something like:

```
Inductive Cmd :=
| Open
| Send
| Close.

Inductive SocketState :=
| Ready
| Opened
| Closed.
```

For example transition from Ready to Opened should happen only after Open command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the formal definition of deterministic finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Formal_definition):

> A deterministic finite automaton `M` is a 5-tuple `Q, Sigma, delta, q0, F`, consisting of
>
> - a finite set of states `Q`
> - a finite set of input symbols called the alphabet `Sigma`
> - a transition function `delta`: `Q * Sigma -> Q`
> - an initial or start state `q0` in `Q`
> - a set of accept states `F` being a subset of `Q`

You gave two out of the five, namely `Q = SocketState` and `Sigma = Cmd`. Assuming that your application has an implicit initial state (probably `Ready`) and no specific "accept states", the only thing needed for your state machine is the **transition function**.

From the definition, the transition function has the type `(SocketState * Cmd) -> SocketState`, but the curried version `SocketState -> Cmd -> SocketState` is equally powerful.

If your state machine has external inputs, add them as parameters to the function. If you want side effects, or some kind of output associated with the transition itself, you can use `SocketState -> Cmd -> (SomeOutput * SocketState)`.

---

#### Edit: Transition as a relation (Extension to [keep_learning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56720407/4595904))

If you want to reason about a series of *valid* commands and transitions, you might want to encode it into a ternary relation instead.

First, let's define what constitutes for valid transitions.

```
Previous state -> (Command) -> Next state
-----------------------------------------
Ready          -> (Open)    -> Opened
Opened         -> (Send)    -> Opened
Opened         -> (Close)   -> Closed
```

Then, encode it as a ternary relation. The following is just an example, similar to [Hoare triples](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Hoare.html) from programming language models.

```
Inductive Transition : SocketState -> Cmd -> SocketState -> Prop :=
  | t_open  : Transition Ready  Open  Opened
  | t_send  : Transition Opened Send  Opened
  | t_close : Transition Opened Close Closed.
```

The above talks about a *single* transition. What about a *series* of transitions? We can define a reflexive-transitive closure, taking a `list` of commands (this is *very* similar to Hoare triples, in the sense that both define a precondition, a sequence of steps, and a postcondition):

```
From Coq Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive TransitionRTC : SocketState -> list Cmd -> SocketState -> Prop :=
  | t_rtc_refl : forall s : SocketState, TransitionRTC s [] s
  | t_rtc_trans1 : forall s1 c s2 clist s3,
      Transition s1 c s2 ->
      TransitionRTC s2 clist s3 ->
      TransitionRTC s1 (c :: clist) s3.
```

The function analogue of RTC relation would be (the `fold_left` in Coq has the last two arguments swapped, compared to Haskell's `foldl` or Ocaml's `fold_left`):

```
Axiom transition : SocketState -> Cmd -> SocketState.
Definition multistep_transition (state0 : SocketState) (clist : list Cmd) :=
  fold_left transition clist state0.
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your rules (transition function) into inductive data type.

```
Inductive Valid_transition : SocketState -> SocketState  -> Type :=
| copen x : x = Open -> Valid_transition Ready Opened (* Input command Open *)
| cready x y : x = Send -> Valid_transition y Opened ->
             Valid_transition Opened Opened (* Send command would not change the 
                                               status of port *)
| cclose x y : x = Close -> Valid_transition y Opened ->
             Valid_transition Opened Closed. (* Close command would close it *)


Check (cready Send _ eq_refl (copen Open eq_refl)).
```

The only way to move from Ready to Opened is first constructor with command Open. The second constructor states that if your command is Send, and you are in Opened state then you would continue to remain in this state. Finally, third constructor closes the open port after receiving Close command. I have encoded a similar transition function as yours (vote counting as state machine), so feel free to have a look at it [1].

[1] https://github.com/mukeshtiwari/EncryptionSchulze/blob/master/code/Workingcode/EncryptionSchulze.v#L718-L740

Comment: Thanks! Looks interesting!